# how to debug javascript in partial view in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**partial view Department**

```
<div>This is deva</div>
<div id="divRead"></div>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $('#divRead').html('<b>This is append debugger</b>');
        })
    </script>
}
```

**Department Action in Account controller**

```
public PartialViewResult Department()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

**Register.cshtml in Account controller**

```
@Html.Partial("Department")
```

how to debugger the jquery in partial view.?

Comment: Developer console in Google Chrome

Comment: @koby Douek:- but partial view data cant display in google chrome

Comment: It doesn't work when in partial view I faced it too. I then kept the js file in main page then I debugged it. Later once I got my js stable I placed back to partial view.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>This is deva</div>
<div id="divRead"></div>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $('#divRead').html('<b>This is append debugger</b>');
        })
    </script>
}
```

give the debugger on where you want to debug. and run the application. after you have to inspect the chrome then it will display in **VM3232** then we have to use the debug.

like below:[image]